# Filtering data using a specific column on a unix system

Tags: awk, grep

I'm trying to filter this data by year, I've tried using the grep command and awk, I need to have the data only for 1975 onwards. Currently, when I run the script I am using I also get data from over year where the *year* appears in the other columns [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aq3oU.png)  This is one example of the code I have tried to use to initially focusing on trying to filter one year.

```
{awk -F, '{ if($1 == "1975") print $0} ' caleq.dat >! regioneq.dat}
```

I have also tried using

```
{grep -F  "1975" caleq.dat >! regioneq.dat}
```

I would be grateful for any assistance. Thank you.

Comment: Welcome to SO, Good that  you have shown your efforts in terms of code. Please do add samples in your question in form of text in CODE TAGS and let us know then.

Comment: please do not use images to show your data.. copy paste a few lines to the question, or manually create a smaller sample and show the output for that sample.. anyways, I think you need `awk -F'/' '$1 == "1975"' caleq.dat` (change the field separator)

Comment: to get the data from 1975, use `awk -F'/' '$1 >= 1975' caleq.dat`

Comment: Hi and welcome to Stack Overflow. Where do the curly braces come from and what about this `>!`? What shell are you using?

Comment: Sorry,   ` >! ` is to have the results exported into a different file instead of printed on the screen as there are several thousand records in the file. This is done using bin shell I think. @ kvantour